# How to create voice activity in application?

Tags: android, gridview, voice

I am creating a new Application for kids. This application is for kids to learn alphabets.

Now I have created a main screen in which alphabets are shown using GridView . Now what I want is, when clicked on particular alphabets it should go to next screen in that screen it should draw an alphabet using lines and then a voice like ('A' for Apple) should be add?

Is any body know how to do that then please help me ...

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
TextToSpeech mTextToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this,new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onInit(int status)
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
    {
      // set language
      int supported = mTextToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);
      if((supported != TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)&&(supported != TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE))
      {
        displayToast("dont support current language");
      }
    }
  } 
});

// start to speak
mTextToSpeech.speak("A for Apple", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);  

// store your voice to file
int r = mTextToSpeech.synthesizeToFile(mEditText.getText().toString(), null, "/mnt/sdcard/speak.wav");
if(r == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) displayToast("save success！");
```